# Calculating hyperbolic distance between two points

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

I was looking for a formula to calculate the hyperbolic distance between two planes and came across this formula

$$\ln\left(\csc b-\cot b\over \csc a - \cot a\right)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are the angles from the positive real axis, with $b$ being the larger angle.

I wanted to confirm if there was another way of finding the hyperbolic distance or if this was it.

Comment: "...came across this formula..." - **where**?

Comment: @J.M. - I don't have the tab open anymore, but it was in one of the links I found through googling

Comment: What model are you using? Wikipedia lists different formulas for [Poincaré disc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_disc), [Poincaré half plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model) and [Beltrami-Klein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model), but one of them might be equivalent to your formula.

Comment: @J.M.: perhaps http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth338/garity/Notes/hyperbolic%20intro.pdf was the source? It has that formula, using $\alpha$ and $\beta$ instead of $a$ and $b$, and giving more details about the center from which the angle should be measured. It indicates use of the upper half plane model.